# Remove Focus from UITextField

Tags: events, ios6, focus, uitextfield

I'm trying to remove focus from a UITextField and even though I resign it from being first responder, I'm still not able to have the cursor not focus on the text field.

I don't have any other input on the view to move the focus to and I don't want to create a dummy one either. What is a good workaround for this?

Comment: If you remove the first responder then cursor won't be focussing on that textfield.

Comment: Does your keyboard dismisses ?

Comment: Yes, the keyboard dismiss. However it still stays in focus.

Comment: Its working fine for me by just calling [self.textField resignFirstResponder]; no need to set the delegate.

Answer (score 6):

As per the documentation.

> To dismiss the keyboard, send the resignFirstResponder message to the text field that is currently the first responder. Doing so causes the text field object to end the current editing session (with the delegate object’s consent) and hide the keyboard.

If you call resignFirstResponder on your textfield then it will end the editing session and the cursor wont be focussing on that textfield.

So please verify one more time whether resignFirstResponder is getting called on that textfield which you want to remove the focus.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely getting called. It's certainly hiding the keyboard and ended editing session as the documentation mention. However, I don't see anything that says that the focus will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set your current class as delegate of your UITextField. I think you forget to set the delegate that's why it's not working as you are expecting.

Comment: Care to explain your logic?